# ターミナルでaltキーが反応しなくなった

Tags: macos, console

macのターミナルにて、`alt+x`を押すと`≈`が出てしまって、Emacs等使えなくなってしまいました。

なぜでしょうか？

Answer (score 4, accepted):

端末(terminal) 上の話ですね？

Preferences -> Profiles -> Keyboard -> Use Option as Meta Key にチェックをつけていないとそうなります。